# Numpy advice for audio filtering using Bayesian statistical analysis on two dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, loops, audio

I'm attempting to create an audio filter which will suppress background noise in a field recordings, using a bayesian statistical approach. Typical audio in the field contains a standard level of background noise, which is in my case unwanted, when I attempt to detect foreground noise.

Using numpy and scipy it is possible to analyse the audio to determine the statistical standard deviation of the sample.

In my environment, foreground noises typically have a power density which is statistically different to the background. i.e. density value >= (2 standard deviations + mean) power density (per dft frequency bin)

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
rate, audio = wavfile.read('test.wav')     

buckets = 64
nperseg = buckets * 2
noverlap = 10

freq, time, density = signal.spectrogram(audio, fs=rate, window='hann',
                                      nperseg=nperseg, noverlap=noverlap,
                                      detrend=False, scaling='density')

stdev = density.std(1)
mean = density.mean(1)
```

**Problem**

I'm hoping to apply a function based on the 2 dimensional numpy array of audio power density  `density` into `results`.  The result is a high contrast, 2 dimensional array of power density where values are either 0.0 or 1.0.

Using the 2 dimensional data, I'm detecting selections of audio recordings ('.wav' files) which either contain or do not contain foreground sound of interest.  I can then chop the file into bite-size chunks, as the need arises.  I have a large number of +100MB wav files, so time is important.

```
results = np.zeros((w,h))
sampleMean = mean.mean() # Average of averages

w,h = density.shape
for ww in range(w):
    for hh in range(h):

        # power density value
        v0 = density[ww][hh]

        # power density cutoff limit
        v1 = (2 * stdev[ww]) + mean[ww]

        if v0 > v1 and v0 > sampleMean:
            results[ww][hh] = 1.0
```

This loop works, but is slow and ugly to boot. It should be able to be written avoiding loops, but I'm somewhat of a numpty numpy noob.  Can I get some assistance?   Better yet if the response is pep8, as I'm learning that also.

Is there a built-in numpy function like a map() function which passes the indices of the array position as arguments?  In this case, I'm not fussed about in-place array manipulation, as I'm also pickling and plotting `density` and `results`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do is extend your stddev matrix and mean matrix to the size of the density array by using np.repeat. So, if you just vectorize instead of using nested for loops, it might speed up significantly. Then you could just do this, I am assuming stdev,v1 and mean to be numpy arrays.

```
v1 = (2*stdev) + mean
v1_new = np.repeat(np.expand_dims(v1,axis=0), repeats = h, axis=0)
result[density>sampleMean and density>v1_new] = 1
```

This will just vectorize the operations instead of having a for loop. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Getting the ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
Attempting results[np.logical_and(Sxp>sampleMean, Sxp >v1_new)] = 1 throws 
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (65,381691) (381691,65)

Comment: You just have to transpose the array, you see the shape sizes are same just use `np.transpose`